# Java lwjgl keyboard handler

Tags: java, input, lwjgl

I've created a class that takes lwjgl's keyboard input and turns it into a list of strings that are all the keys that are currently being pressed.

```
public class KeyHandler {

    ArrayList<String> keysPressed;

    public KeyHandler() {
        keysPressed = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void checkKeys() {
        while (Keyboard.next()) {
            String keystring = Keyboard.getKeyName(Keyboard.getEventKey());
            if (!keysPressed.contains(keystring)) {
                keysPressed.add(keystring); // key has been pressed
            } else {
                keysPressed.remove(keystring); // key has been released
            }
        }
    }

    public void runKeys() {
    if (keysPressed.size() > 0) {
        for (String str : keysPressed) {
            System.out.println("Key handler got key:" + str);
            // run class for key
        }
    } else {
        // no keys have been pressed
    }
}

}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way so that 'runKeys' will run a class with that name, for example.

W.java

```
public class W {

    public static void exc() {
        player.moveZ(10);
    }

}
```

The reason for doing this is to avoid having to run through 50+ if statements to check for input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a `Map<Character, Consumer<Character>>`.
- Create a class for each character which implements `Consumer<Character>` interface.
- Store objects of those classes in the map.
- Call consume on the appropriate consumer object from the map using your detected keystroke character.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's a little fiddly setting up every key, but it does work, thank you :)

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Good luck.